# Ruby on Rails 4: when type rails server , got error message PG::ConnectionBad

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4

I am new to Ruby on rails. I've created basic demo apps by tutorial learning by examples.

First it working fine, one week later i got error when type `rails s`,

Error

```
PG::ConnectionBad
could not connect to server: No such file or directory Is the server running      
locally and accepting connections on Unix domain socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

I am using PostgreSQL database.

I am on MAC OS X 10.8.5

I have found similar questions on SO, but they are experiencing at some advance stage and thus involves some advance solutions.

when type

```
which psql
/usr/local/bin/psql
```

Comment: delete this file `postgres/postmaster.pid` and try, have you upgraded your os recently

Comment: Can you tell us how you installed Postgres — for example, did you use homebrew? It would be great if you could run the command `which psql` in your Terminal and add the result to your question.

Comment: Try to check this

Start Postgres:
pg_ctl -D /usr/local/var/postgres -l /usr/local/var/postgres/server.log start

Stop Postgres:

pg_ctl -D /usr/local/var/postgres stop -s -m fast

Comment: yes  Sontya, i upgrade  os

Comment: I install psql with homebrew

Comment: when type which psql '/usr/local/bin/psql'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems upgrading your OS has changed the permissions on the directory where Postgres keeps its data.

Run

```
sudo chown -R sabir:staff /usr/local/var/postgres
```

to make your user account the owner of that directory. Enter your password when it asks for it; you will not see the characters as you enter them.

The homebrew version of Postgres includes the ability to start automatically. To check whether your installation does, run

```
ls -l ~/Library/LaunchAgents/
```

You should see a line ending with `homebrew.mxcl.postgresql.plist`. If you do not see this line, run

```
ln -sfv /usr/local/opt/postgresql/*.plist ~/Library/LaunchAgents
```

in order to have it start automatically.

Finally, run

```
launchctl unload ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.postgresql.plist
launchctl load ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.postgresql.plist
```

to make sure Postgres is active now. Confirm by typing

```
psql -l
```

Comment: when i type `launchctl unload ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.postgresql.plist`

Comment: `launchctl: Dubious permissions on file (skipping): /Users/Sabir/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.postgresql.plist
nothing found to unload`

Comment: Did you execute the second command, `launchctl load`? Does `psql -l` work? If not, please post the output of `ls -lh ~/Library/LaunchAgents`

Comment: output of  `ls -lh ~/Library/LaunchAgents`  `total 40
-rw-r--r--  1 Sabir  staff   697B 12 Dec 10:43 com.adobe.AAM.Updater-1.0.plist
-rw-r--r--  1 Sabir  staff   425B  5 Jan 22:53 com.apple.FolderActions.enabled.plist
-rw-r--r--  1 Sabir  staff   517B 17 Feb 08:22 com.apple.FolderActions.folders.plist
-r-xr-xr-x  1 Sabir  staff   457B 10 Dec 21:39 com.citrixonline.GoToMeeting.G2MUpdate.plist
lrwxr-xr-x  1 Sabir  staff    56B 17 Feb 20:11 homebrew.mxcl.postgresql.plist -> /usr/local/opt/postgresql/homebrew.mxcl.postgresql.plist`

Comment: `launchctl load ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.postgresql.plist` out is `launchctl: Dubious permissions on file (skipping): /Users/Sabir/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.postgresql.plist
nothing found to load`

Comment: Okay. Please run `sudo chown Sabir:staff /usr/local/opt/postgresql/homebrew.mxcl.postgresql.plist`, and try launctl load again.

Comment: same problem, when i run `launchctl unload`

Comment: 'launchctl: Dubious permissions on file (skipping): /Users/Sabir/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.postgresql.plist
nothing found to unload'

Comment: Okay, but what about `load`?

Comment: `launchctl: Dubious permissions on file (skipping): /Users/Sabir/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.postgresql.plist
nothing found to load`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71087/discussion-between-janfoeh-and-mary-smith).

Answer (score 0):

When you install postgres using homebrew, than maybe you just started it manually in foreground. So after closing the terminal window postgres was not running anymore.

I'd suggest to do the following steps:

- Check if postgres is running by grepping the process list: `ps aux | grep postgres`
- if it's running try to `sudo kill -9 {POSTGRES_PID}`
- if not running, use `brew info postgres` to see how to start it manually (or on startup etc.)
- start postgres with the result from homebrew - in my case `postgres -D /usr/local/var/postgres`

I hope, that will help you out.
If you installed postgres on another basis, I can change my answer accordingly.

Comment: postgres -D /usr/local/var/postgres   FATAL:  data directory "/usr/local/var/postgres" has wrong ownership
HINT:  The server must be started by the user that owns the data directory.

Comment: @MarySmith please run `ls -l /usr/local/var/postgres` and tell us the result. Also, please run `whoami`, which returns your Mac username.

Comment: run `ls -l /usr/local/var/postgres`   `total 1288
-rwxrwxrwx   1 root  wheel       4 28 Aug 15:22 PG_VERSION
drwxrwxrwx  51 root  wheel    1734 28 Nov 16:42 base
drwxrwxrwx  43 root  wheel    1462 23 Jan 10:26 global
drwxrwxrwx   3 root  wheel     102 28 Aug 15:22 pg_clog
-rwxrwxrwx   1 root  wheel    4467 28 Aug 15:22 pg_hba.conf
-rwxrwxrwx   1 root  wheel    1636 28 Aug 15:22 pg_ident.conf
drwxrwxrwx   4 root  wheel     136 28 Aug 15:22 pg_multixact
drwxrwxrwx   3 root  wheel     102 23 Jan 10:25 pg_notify
---------- -----

`

Comment: run whoami display my username

Comment: @MarySmith I know, but I need to know your username :) Also, could you please write @ janfoeh (without the space) when you answer my comments? That way, SO notifies me of your reply.

Comment: @janfoeh my username is `sabir`